# Graph API User Delta URL

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

1: Delta URL isn’t reflecting certain kinds of Users.
But Without the Delta, those Users show up. 
Although unable to figure what kind of data doesn’t reflect for a User Query with a DELTA URL.
It would be great to understand
i:Are Alias Updates reflected in Delta
ii:If Primary Mail Attribute is NULL, will those show up in Delta.
iii: As a part of Delta, I am selecting specifically Mail, ProxyAddresses attributes. For Certain Users this doesn’t show up in Delta but only without a Delta URL when pulled,  these show up.

Answer (score 0):

> i:Are Alias Updates reflected in Delta

Yes.

> ii:If Primary Mail Attribute is NULL, will those show up in Delta?

Yes.

> iii: As a part of Delta, I am selecting specifically Mail,
>   ProxyAddresses attributes. For Certain Users this doesn’t show up in
>   Delta but only without a Delta URL when pulled, these show up.

Delta query is used for discovering newly created, updated, or deleted entities without performing a full read of the target resource with every request. If you want to find a user, please use user request url.

Comment: Thanks for the INfo. But i am not trying to Find a User. User already Exists. But Update to that User is missing in DELTA.

Comment: @user6230298 Which user property did you change?

Comment: Added Alias to the user.